# Does Google's GTMOAuth2Authentication client support granting offline access?

Tags: iphone, picasa

I'm trying to get a request token for Picasa to access albums and photos offline. I was able to request for it from the server side using these two params (access_type and approval_prompt) but i'm not sure how to pass them for the iPhone client (GTMOAuth2Authentication and GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch).

access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You set the parameters in the GTMOAuth2SignIn additionalAuthorizationParameters property before making the request.

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;

[[viewController signIn] setAdditionalAuthorizationParameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline",@"force", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"access_type",@"approval_prompt", nil]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)showGoogleLoginPage{
    SEL finishedSelector = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authViewController =
    [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                               clientID:kClientID
                                           clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                       keychainItemName:userKeyChainName
                                               delegate:self
                                       finishedSelector:finishedSelector];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray
                                                                              arrayWithObjects:@"offline",@"force",@"en", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"access_type",@"approval_prompt",@"hl", nil]];

    authViewController.signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile = YES;
    authViewController.signIn.additionalAuthorizationParameters=params;
    [self presentViewController:authViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

> hope this help for you..